# Why array size is incorrect ? And how to rectify it?

Tags: c

The outputs should be 10 and 40( considering sizeof(int) = 4) but while printing,
sizeof(arr) is 4. Why is this so ? I am leaving a screenshot of my code below.

```
int n = 10, *arr;
arr = ( int * ) malloc ( sizeof(int) * n );
```

[image]

Comment: "The outputs should be ... 40" --> Disagree,  `arr` is  a pointer and not an array. The size of a pointer far more likely has a size of 4 or 8.

Comment: It is baffling *why* you want to find the size of the array, when in the line above, you *told* `malloc` the size to allocate - `sizeof(int) * n`. If you want to know if `malloc` was successfull, you check `arr == NULL`.